# Can I add my Global Entry (Redress) Number after booking a ticket?

Tags: usa, global-entry, qantas, expedia, trusted-traveler

I booked my ticket on Expedia and the airline is Qantas. I was in the process of being approved for global entry when I booked the ticket. Now that I've been approved, I want to enter my information to avoid any problems.

I've gone through Expedia and Qantas booking information and I don't see where I can enter the number anymore. It had a spot to enter it when booking the ticket on Expedia, but it's no longer there.

Is this even possible, or do I need to contact Expedia/Qanta support?

I do have my card, so I'm not sure if I even *need* to enter the information, or just show it at the ticket counter when I'm at the airport.

I will be traveling from Fort Worth, USA to Auckland, NZ

Comment: Global Entry and Redress numbers are two different things.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, I wasn't aware of that. I'm new to this whole process

Comment: @NateEldredge I will be traveling from Dallas/Ft Worth to Auckland NZ. If that's the case then it seems simple enough to present the card at the kiosk

Comment: I take back the previous comment - the thing about card at a kiosk is wrong.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason to enter your Global Entry PASSID in the airline's booking system would be so that you can qualify for TSA PreCheck when you depart from the US, with expedited security screening (no taking off your shoes, etc).  Your PreCheck status has to be shown on your boarding pass (having the Global Entry card itself does not help).  However, Qantas is not a [participating airline](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/participating-airlines) in TSA PreCheck, so in this case you can't do that.  You will have to go through regular screening as you depart from Dallas.

When you return to the US, after getting off the plane, you can use your passport (not your Global Entry card!) at the Global Entry kiosk for expedited *immigration* processing.  This does not require any sort of advance registration with the airline, as far as I know.

So, short answer: there is nothing you can or should do with your Global Entry number, or your card, on this trip.

Also note that Global Entry and TSA PreCheck are entirely unrelated to [redress numbers](https://www.dhs.gov/redress-control-numbers), except that some booking systems let you enter the numbers in the same place.  Redress numbers are meant for  people who, for instance, have been mistakenly put on no-fly lists because they have a similar name to a suspected terrorist.

Comment: Thank you for this information, it's really good to know!